# Cholesky decomposition for singular PSD matrix?

Tags: scipy, linear-algebra, numerical-methods

Can anyone suggest a way to get Cholesky decomposition of rank deficient Gram matrix in scipy?

I need something that keeps the original ordering so it's equivalent to Cholesky LDL decomposition for full-rank case. My attempt below with `scipy.linalg.ldl` is giving me different orders

```
import numpy as np
from scipy import linalg
def modified_cholesky(arr):
    """Use Cholesky to produce LDL' factorization of arr."""
    chol = linalg.cholesky(arr, lower=True)
    d1 = np.diag(np.diag(chol))
    L = chol@linalg.inv(d1)
    return L, d1

def modified_ldl(arr):
    lu, d, perm=linalg.ldl(arr, lower=True)
    lu2 = lu[perm,:]
    return lu2, np.sqrt(d), perm

# sanity checks
arr=np.array([[ 3.,  5.], [ 5., 11.]])
mchol, d = modified_cholesky(arr)
np.testing.assert_allclose(mchol @ d @ d @ mchol.T, arr, rtol=1e-6, atol=1e-7)
mchol2, d2, perm = modified_ldl(arr)
np.testing.assert_allclose(mchol2 @ d2 @ d2 @ mchol2.T, arr[perm,:][:,perm], rtol=1e-6, atol=1e-7)

np.testing.assert_allclose(mchol, mchol2)  # fails because linalg.ldl is permuted
modified_cholesky(np.array([[1,1],[1,1]]))  # fails with 2-th leading minor of the array is not positive definite
```

Comment: might attract more attention at the specialized [Computational Science SE](https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/). Consider re-posting there, if the # views is too low at SO.

Comment: What do you want to do with the factor? Note that it will be singular, so you cant directly use it to solve equations.

Comment: @dmuir I need it for as a metric to compare quality of approximation to the inverse Hessian preconditioner (using euclidian distance between their cholesky factors). The ultimate metric is to see how well the preconditioned gradient descent works, but needed a cheaper proxy